# How long should I wait to receive a performance review?

Tags: communication, salary, work-environment, performance-reviews

I have been at my current position for over a year and a half currently as a full time employee, and also have worked part time before that.  (so almost two years in total)

I was under the impression that most companies conduct bi-annual/annual/semi-annual reviews of their employees (which sometimes includes a salary increase)

After I passed my 1 year mark I let it pass, but on 6/20 I asked about receiving a review, and was told within two weeks I should have one.  On 7/26 it was mentioned to me that they have not forgotten about a review, but I *still* have not heard anything about it.

I am wondering **how long should I wait before asking again, or doing something else about receiving my review/salary increase.**

At this point I have missed out on a possible 3-6 months of increased wages, but that's not something I could likely bring up in a meeting.

I'm not trying to come off as greedy, or as a "needy" employee, but I just want to make sure I am on track in the eyes of a manager.  Also I believe that I am consistently adding value to the company, so a raise would be appreciated.  The fact that we are continually hiring new people leads me to believe that we have money to put towards that as well.

Comment: Why do you think you need a performance review to get a wage increase? Just tell them you want a meeting to discuss something important and then request a raise. Dont wait for them to hand it out to you.

Comment: @ayrtonclark I assumed that was standard operating procedure.  Being my first job out of college I don't have much experience with this sort of thing, and I'm unsure of what is common since it likely changes per organization.

Comment: *I asked about receiving a review* Did you confirm that this is something they normally do or did you just ask to have a review of your performance? If this isn't part of their normal operating procedure, they might not realize (or may pretend not to realize) that you're actually trying to get a raise.

Comment: @BSMP It is something they are actively doing with others - I asked for a performance review.

Comment: Just make sure that any pay increases are retroactive to the anniversary date. It's not your fault that they've dragged their feet on completing the formal process.  It's pretty standard that if the review is supposed to cover a one-year period, that they back-date the increases.  But don't assume, be specific, and if they try to make it effective the later date, I would not sign off on the evaluation until that is corrected.

Comment: In that case I'd say the fact that your current employer does these reviews is more important than whether or not most companies do them.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Okay - I just wasn't sure if It was "ok" to ask for the back dated pay from when I originally requested the review as well - thank you for the clarification.

Comment: FWIW, I probably would not assume to confirm it was back-dated unless that was written somewhere in your employement contract.  It definitely could make you seem needy/greedy IMO and may even reflect on your future reviews (or even your present one).  IMO, anytime you ask for anything, you need to be willing to accept the risk if things go awry (and then you can ask pretty much anything=)).

Comment: @confusedandamused It's pretty standard to ask for a raise in a performance review, but there's nothing saying you cant just go and ask for one if you think your underpaid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they responded to you 36 days after you asked saying they're still on it, I would give it at least that much before asking again.  Often day to day can replace things that happen infrequently (even if on a year/2 year schedule) and things need to get pushed out.  Responding more frequently than them will make you seem needy (not even just about salary).
Note, I probably would have said a month would be reasonable if they did not get back to you at all.

Not what you asked in the title, but only ~1/4 of the companies I've been employed by did performance reviews.  It sounds like you're more sure they do them in your comments than you were in the question but certainly not every company does and also not all performance reviews associate with salary increases either.

You may also consider asking your coworkers (peers) if they had reviews.  This would clarify if your company does indeed conduct them as well as find out more about them.  It is a perfect time for you now to gather this information, under a guise (or in honesty just curious) about how they are conducted since you (hypothetcally) have one upcoming.

If worried coming across needy/greedy you may want to consider how often you'd ask if you knew there was no salary increase attached to the review (or if you had a review and got no increase).

Also I think it's noteworthy that companies have tons of expenses outside of salary (such as hiring) and even if you were making improvements/contributions more than another whole human being, it's unlikely companies will see it that way.  That's not to say you don't deserve an increase, it's just usually they are distinct things in business.

Comment: ` It sounds like you're more sure they do them in your comments than you were in the question` - Yeah it's becoming a more formal thing the process is still new, but the company is generally smaller than a large corp.

Comment: @confusedandamused Gotcha.  I generally think some patience as it becomes more formal is also warrented.